# Can anyone check the code I am having problems when I put 100 in

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, max, min

When 100 is put in the code the code goes -inf and I am not getting what is the problem.

```
import math
ran = int(input("Input range: "))
max_limit = -math.inf
min_limit = math.inf
summation = 0
for times in range(ran):
    x = int(input("Input an integer: "))
    summation += x
    if x < min_limit:
        min_limit = x
    elif x > max_limit:
        max_limit = x
print("Maximum:", max_limit, "Minimum", min_limit)
print("Summation", summation)
```

Comment: The very first number you enter will be both less than `min_limit`, and greater than `max_limit`.  But you only update one of those variables, due to using `elif` instead of `if` for the second check.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you use `elif`, and this can result that only min or max will change,

```
# x == 100
if x < min_limit:
        min_limit = x # In here
elif x > max_limit: # will be skipped because its inside an `else` statement
        max_limit = x # not here
```

simple change into

```
import math
ran = int(input("Input range: "))
max_limit = -math.inf
min_limit = math.inf
summation = 0
for times in range(ran):
    x = int(input("Input an integer: "))
    summation += x
    if x < min_limit:
        min_limit = x
    if x > max_limit:
        max_limit = x
print("Maximum:", max_limit, "Minimum", min_limit)
print("Summation", summation)
```

also you can do it with `list` object as this:

```py
ran = int(input("Input range: "))
l = [int(input("Input an integer: ")) for times in range(ran)]
print("Maximum:", max(l), "Minimum", min(l))
print("Summation", sum(l))
```